# Python download images with changing variables

Tags: python, image, url, urllib, python-3.5

I want to download images from an URL link which has a `random component` in it, so i have generated a code to do the same, but i'm getting an error -

Code:

```
import urllib.request
import random

random_number=random.randint(500,600)

url_image="'https://csgostash.com/img/skins/s"+str(random_number)+"fn.png'"

image=urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_image, 'skin.png')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/luke/Desktop/scraper/test image download/cs test.py", line 8, in <module>
    image=urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_image, 'skin.png')
  File "C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 187, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 488, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1310, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: 'https>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, url_image has an weird syntax.

```
    url_image="https://csgostash.com/img/skins/s"+str(random_number)+"fn.png"
```

If you fix this, you will notice an 403 - Vax! Protection against bot: use a user agent.

```
import urllib.request
import random

random_number=random.randint(500,600)
url_image="https://csgostash.com/img/skins/s"+str(random_number)+"fn.png"

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
req = urllib.request.Request(url_image, None, headers)


print(url_image)
#image, h = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_image)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()

print (the_page)
```

Edit: ofcourse you may save to file:

```
with open('skin.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(the_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this project](https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/download_images) using requests.

[image]